# select multiple column by group and time in mssql

Tags: sql-server

I have one database where I want to get one column data clubbed by every hour in a date.

table structure is as below

```
id Time                      Activity
1  2015-11-25 13:43:01.787      1
2  2015-11-25 13:43:01.787      2
3  2015-11-25 23:43:01.787      0
4  2015-11-26 12:43:01.787      2
5  2015-11-27 23:43:01.787      1
```

so data output below of it should be if no date is passed

```
Date        Hour   TotalActivity
2015-11-25   13         3
2015-11-23   23         0
2015-11-26   12         2
2015-11-27   23         1
```

I have created a query with some sort of help

```
SELECT CAST(Time as date) AS ForDate,Activity,
       DATEPART(hour,Time) AS OnHour,
       COUNT(*) AS Totals
FROM cellinfo
GROUP BY CAST(Time as date), Activity,
       DATEPART(hour,Time)
```

but am not able to concat result of activity column and
also not able to apply where query for selecting data of particular date need some sort of help in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok after some struggle I was able to get the answer

```
SELECT CAST(Time as date) AS ForDate,
    sum(Activity) as act,
    DATEPART(hour,Time) AS OnHour,
    COUNT(*) AS Totals
    FROM cellinfo where Time BETWEEN '2015-12-04 00:00:00' AND '2015-12-04 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY CAST(Time as date),
    DATEPART(hour,Time)
```

but still am looking for good answer of not selecting date with between time thing.